# image move in pygame (crashes pygame)

Tags: python, while-loop, pygame

i'm trying to make a game and when this loop runs, it crashes pygame

```
while poterbar_hunt_pone == True and ptwo_shot == True:

            if poterbarx < xone+carone_width:
                poterbar_dir = "right"
                poterbarx_c = 20
            else:
                poterbar_dir = "left"
                poterbarx_c = -20

            if poterbary+poterbarh < yone:
                poterbary_c = 20
            else:
                poterbary_c = -20

            if poterbarx <= xone+carone_width and poterbarx+poterbarw >= xone:

                if poterbary+poterbarh >= yone and poterbary <= yone+carone_height:
                    xone_change = random.randrange (-20, 20)
                    yone_change = random.randrange (-20, 20)
                    poterbar_hunt_pone = False
                    ptwo_shot = False
                    poterbarx = -100
                    poterbary = -100
```

when both values are True pygame crashes and i think is in the movement of poterbar.
if anyone of you guys know about what causes pygame to crash please let me know

Comment: Can you tell us what error it raises and if there are more files ( Wich I think there are) , what's the code for them?

Comment: in console i have no errors...it's just the pygame that crashes

Comment: If there's no errors then it's just pygame naturally ending, not a crash. In which case, I encourage you to examine your loop condition. For more help, I think you'll need to provide more context of your code.

Comment: it's not like this... whenever this part of code runs the pygame window crashes, no quiting pygame..just crashes.

Comment: If it's crashing, it will raise an error, if not it's most likely just closing. Either way you will need to provide more code or information.

Comment: When Pygame crashes, do you mean the window says "not responding", or something similar?  Please give us some symptoms to we may give a diagnosis.

Comment: what do you mean `crash` ? when you run in console (a) it closes Pygame window without error message but console is still open (probably it is not crash but you made some mistake in code and Pygame leave all loops), (b) it closes console window (it is real crash and it may means problem with SDL library)

Comment: it crashes only pygame window "is not responding" windows error. please guys if anyone know what cause is it..if you need all of my code i can't provide them but i can attatch the .py file

Comment: I downloaded the code from the link below.  The code runs OK for me - no crash, no lockup. Some images bounce around the screen.  However I used my own (small) PNGs.   I'm using Python3 on Linux.  The screen needs to be cleared (painted black/background) on each loop.  All those `if yone <= ... and xone <= ...` code lines should be factored out into some kind of number-array with a loop (or at least a single function), it's much easier debugging a *small* program.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `pygame.display.update()`.

Add this at the very bottom of your code, so now it looks like:

```
while poterbar_hunt_pone == True and ptwo_shot == True:

            if poterbarx < xone+carone_width:
                poterbar_dir = "right"
                poterbarx_c = 20
            else:
                poterbar_dir = "left"
                poterbarx_c = -20

            if poterbary+poterbarh < yone:
                poterbary_c = 20
            else:
                poterbary_c = -20

            if poterbarx <= xone+carone_width and poterbarx+poterbarw >= xone:

                if poterbary+poterbarh >= yone and poterbary <= yone+carone_height:
                    xone_change = random.randrange (-20, 20)
                    yone_change = random.randrange (-20, 20)
                    poterbar_hunt_pone = False
                    ptwo_shot = False
                    poterbarx = -100
                    poterbary = -100
    pygame.display.update() # You have to update display
```

Comment: Since you didn't show us the rest of the code, this is what I suspect is the problem. Providing more context will allow us to help you better.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B19TUzutKvc-QlROV2VST3lPOHM?usp=sharing
Here you can find my project on the g.drive